# What does the CSS Selector > * do from within a Vue.js component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

While exploring the new Vuestic admin dashboard tool, I discovered a UI bug where the donut was oversized in relation to its containing element. I was trying to debug/fix it so I could submit a PR, but I ran into an odd CSS selector `> *` during debugging for the [Vue Chart Base class](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin/blob/master/src/components/vuestic-components/vuestic-chart/VuesticChart.vue#L44) which didn't quite make sense to me.

**How I interpreted what `> *` would do in CSS**:
since [`>` selector in CSS](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_child.html) gets ALL children, and the [`*` selector in CSS](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_all.html) gets EVERY element on the page, I thought perhaps that using this selector means to get EVERY CHILD element.

When used in context of a Vue Component, I believe that CSS is scoped to that component, so is my interpretation correct, or am I mistaken?

Comment: It selects all direct children

Comment: @JonUleis: isn't the XML definition of children "the next level down"? More than one level down is a "grandchild" or "descendent", I think. (Same distinction applies to parent versus grandparent/ancestor).

Comment: This statement _"the `*` selector in CSS gets EVERY element on the page"_ may be useful for most practical purposes, but it is technically incorrect. The _[Universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)_ matches an element of any type. Whether or not that means _every_ element on the page depends on the context in which it is used. For example `div > * > em` would select all grandchildren of a div (exactly grand-children, not children and not further descendents) regardless of the type of the intervening element.

Answer (score 1):

`> *` will select every element that is a child-element of *something*, which essentially is everything except the root node of the DOM.

However, this rule with the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) `*` has low [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so other rules will easily override it, making it useful as a fallback rule.

Where that rule applies depends on the context in which it's defined. If your Vue component creates nodes in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) and the CSS is defined there then the rule should only apply within that scope.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all child elements of parent, so `parent > *` is equal to 'parent > childElements' (**but not children of children!**). I have added the snippet for example. Here i'm changing the `background-color` of all child elements of `<div id="first"></div>` to black using `#first > * {background-color: black;}`:

```css
#first {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: violet
}

#second {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px;
}

#first > * {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how interpreted while on a line by itself in the component's styling rules (meaning it is not prefixed by a DOM tag, ID, Class such as:

``` ul > * {...}```
``` #myId > * { ...} ```
``` .myClass > * {...}```

In the link I provided to the Vue.js component that I am asking about in the context of this question, there is no prefixed / target parent element defined. So...does that mean that without any explicitly defined parent, whatever the containing element is...is implicitly defined as the parent or would the **greedy** `*` selector override that without a parent explicitly defined?

Comment: @BenjaminDean, does this rules applied?